# model.save setting the url and making a call back on success

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model, callback

I'm trying to get this method to work:

```
that.model.save(null,  // I'm calling that.model because this is nested in another method
{
   url: 'some url',

    success: function(model, response) {
        // update stuff
    }, 
    error: function(model, response) {
        // throw error. 
    }
});
```

but for some reason it does not call the success method or the error method. 
where the comments are I I'm calling methods... I don't want to get into the specifics of all the methods I'm calling. also the save method works, it just does not call eater of those methods.

also if i try and just call a method that I alrady made like:

```
success: that.somemethod()
```

javascript throws: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a first note, `success: that.somemethod()` can't work as I'm pretty sure `that.somemethod` isn't a function (I could be mistaken though).

Comment: @Loamhoof: Don't you mean "`that.somemethod` doesn't *return* a function"?

Comment: @muistooshort yup, forgot the parenthesis. Editing that. Well, can't in fact. So "`that.somemethod()` isn't a function"

Answer (score 1):

The method looks fine as it uses the same arguments as Backbone describes:

```
model.save([attributes], [options])
```

The most likely scenario is that your success/error handlers are being overridden somewhere up the prototype chain and not calling your handlers.

Answer (score 1):

First, you must bind instance method and then assign it to success

```
that.model.save(null,  // I'm calling that.model because this is nested in another method
{
    url: 'some url',

    success: _.bind(that.mySuccessMethod, that), 
    error:   _.bind(that.myErrorMethod, that)
});
```